# How do I create an F# mutable option type?

Tags: types, f#, option-type, mutable

I need to create a mutable `option<T>` type in F#. I've tried writing

```
let x = ref None
```

and subsequently writing

```
x := Some(z)
```

but it doesn't work. Help!

Comment: Just wondering, but why would you ever need a mutable option?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to state the type explicitly to avoid ["the Value Restriction"](http://strangelights.com/fsharp/wiki/default.aspx/FSharpWiki/ValueRestriction.html) (or see ["Automatic Generalization" on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233183(VS.100).aspx)):

```
let x : Ref<int option> = ref None

x := Some 4
```

Answer (score 4):

Also note that you face this problem only when entering the code in F# interacative line-by-line. If you enter the first line without providing type annotations, you'll get the error:

```
> let x = ref None;;
// Tests.fsx(1,7): error FS0030: Value restriction.
```

However, if you enter a larger porition of code that uses the `x` ref cell (for example assigns a value to it) then F# will be able to infer the type from the later part of the code, so you won't need any type annotations. For example:

```
> let x = ref None
  x := Some(10);;
```

This will work fine, because F# will infer the type of `x` from the second line. This means that you probably shouldn't need any type annotations if you'll send the code to F# interactively for testing in larger portions (and in a compiled F# code, you'll almost never face this problem).